# Derivatives on a graph of $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

So I'm learning derivatives (yay!) and I have this math problem where I am looking at a graph of $f'(x)$.

[image: Graph]

I am trying to find the values where:

- $f(x)$ greatest
- $f(x)$ least
- $f'(x)$ greatest
- $f'(x)$ least
- $f''(x)$ greatest
- $f''(x)$ least

So I am thinking that for $f(x)$

$f(x)$ greatest: **F** because the graph is increasing and **A** represents the highest point

$f(x)$ least: **A** because this is the lowest point on the graph

$f'(x)$ greatest: **A** because this is the absolute maximum

$f'(x)$ least: **C** because this is the absolute minimum

$f''(x)$ greatest: **D** because this is concave up

$f''(x)$ least: **B** because this is concave down

Am I correct? Just trying to learn and explain my thinking :)

Comment: I agree $f''$ is smallest near $B$, but you might want to explain how you know $f''(B)$ is less than $f''(E)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers are all correct, but I would express your reasons differently. For the first two questions, I would say "because $f$ is increasing on the interval" instead of "because the graph is increasing", or even "because $f'$ is positive so $f$ is increasing" - the graph depicts $f'$, which isn't strictly increasing, it's just positive. Similarly, I would say "$f''$ is greatest at $\mathbf{D}$ because $f'$ is increasing the fastest there" - it's not clear what "this" is referring to when you say "this is concave up" (you mean $f$ is concave up, but just from reading your explanation, I would assume you meant $f'$ was concave up).